# Склонение слова "Скайп"

Tags: склонение

В устной речи часто слышу: "увидимся в "Скайпе", "разговаривал по "Скайпу". Как правильно употреблять это слово?  Нужны ли кавычки на письме?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Юридически - нужны. Слово не вошло в словари, нарицательным не стало. Поэтому - "Скайп".
Фактически же словари в силу своей консервативности просто не успели откликнуться на языковые реалии. Скайп в разговорном языке стал вполне привычен и заслуживает обычной строчной буквы без кавычек.

Кстати, нечто подобное происходит с самим интернетом, который по словарю Лопатина требует заглавной, что встречает активное неприятие почти всех пишущих.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, "интернет" уже официально разрешено писать с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Не видел пока. А кем? И что вообще такое "официально"?

Answer (score 3):

Это название программы, обычно пишут Skype или Скайп, в Скайпе. Но кто-то пишет и с маленькой буквы, подразумевая просто  голосовое общения через Интернет.